# How to set the columns in a dataframe even when one of the columns doesn't exist?

Tags: python, pandas

I am compiling a list of dataframes from ReST endpoints (so from json results).  In some cases, during the final steps, when I set the final set of columns I receive a KeyError exception.

```
images_df = pd.concat(images)
images_df = images_df[list(cvpc.images_columns.keys())]
```

What I would like to know is, is there a way to set the columns in such a way that non-existent columns are simply created with null values?

I've also tried to set the columns before appending to the list of dataframes, i.e.:

```
temp_df = temp_df[list(cvpc.images_columns.keys())]
images.append(temp_df)
```

So if I can get the columns to "create" even when they don't exist this would be a huge win as setting columns sooner can help keep the final list of images to a minimal size.

Here's a simple example:

```
data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df_t = pd.DataFrame(data)

final_columns = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']
df = df_t[final_columns]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df_t = pd.DataFrame(data)

final_columns = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']

for col in final_columns:
   if col not in df_t.columns:
      df_t[col] = np.NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

you could create a dictionary and unpack it using `assign` for non existing columns, then simply slice the columns as you've done above with a list.

```
import numpy as np
df = df_t.assign(**{col : np.nan for col in final_columns if col not in df_t.columns}
           )[final_columns]

print(df)

   col_1 col_2  col_3
0      3     a    NaN
1      2     b    NaN
2      1     c    NaN
3      0     d    NaN
```

Comment: I tried this one but it did not work when I got to the step where I set the final set of columns, after executing the above I then tried `df_t = df_t[final_columns` to ensure my final dataframe contained only the desired columns, i.e. if there were a col_2_5 that I didn't want.  This could be due to my not covering this aspect especially well in my example.

Comment: I'll test again, but in my initial test I ended up with a KeyError again for missing columns even though the first answer, accepted, worked.

Answer (score 0):

I will assign empty columns filled with NaN values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df_t = pd.DataFrame(data)

final_columns = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']
for x in final_columns:
  if not x in list(df_t.columns.values):
    df_t[x] = np.nan

df = df_t[final_columns]
```

Later you can fill the NaN columns.